# How to retrieve UIImage from UIDragItem?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a UIViewController that contains two UICollectionViews.  I am dragging and droppping images from the first UIcollectionView to the second one.  My drag implementation so far works but I am unable to retrieve the underlying data that is being dragged, in this case the image.  Below is my code.

```
extension StartGameViewController: UICollectionViewDragDelegate{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {

    print("ITEM DRAGGED INDEX: \(indexPath)")
    // objects for drag and drop must support the NSItemProviderWriting protocol
    // Conforming type : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsitemproviderwriting
    var arrayDragitem = [UIDragItem]()
    guard let arrayData = self.puzzlePieces else{ return []}
    let puzzlePiece = arrayData[indexPath.row]
    let image = puzzlePiece.image
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider.init(object: image) // UIImage conforms to NSItemProviderWriting
    let dragItem = UIDragItem.init(itemProvider: itemProvider)
    arrayDragitem.append(dragItem)
    return arrayDragitem
}
}

extension StartGameViewController: UICollectionViewDropDelegate{

// Required - Tells your delegate to incorporate the drop data into the collection view.
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {

    let destinationIndex = coordinator.destinationIndexPath
    let dropItems = coordinator.items
    let dragItem = dropItems[0].dragItem

    guard let image = dragItem.localObject as? UIImage else{
            print("data retrieval error")
            return
    }
    print("image.size: \(image.size)")
}
```

Comment: The image in not in `localObject`, it's in the item provider. Basically do the opposite of `itemsForBeginning` in `performDropWith`. Get the `NSItemProvider` from the `UIDragItem`. Then get the image from the item provider (which isn't trivial). Try a search on "NSItemProvider UIImage".

Comment: @rmaddy would it be possible for you to elaborate please.  Been doing some searches as you suggested but not coming up with much.